# Fill the y axis in the back of a boxplot graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, boxplot

I have this boxplot graph:

```
# Importing necessary libraries
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns


# Size of the plot in inches
plt.figure(figsize=(11, 6))

# Boxplot of the data
ax = sns.boxplot(x="CÓD. ESTAÇÃO", y="CHUMBO", data=df, linewidth=1, palette='Blues')

# Adjusting the y-axis range
ax.set_ylim(min(df['CHUMBO']) - 0.01, max(df['CHUMBO']) + 0.01)

# Adding title to the plot
plt.title("Boxplot of lead content by station", loc="center", fontsize=18)
plt.xlabel("Station Codes")
plt.ylabel("Lead Content")
ax.set_ylim(-0, 0.045)

# Displaying the plot
plt.show()
```

[image: boxplot]

I need to fill the layers with colors just like this one:

[image: boxplot and layers]

The last one was created in R but I was trying to create it with Python using Matplotlib. I haven't seen any example on how to do this on the internet.

I've tried `plt.fill_between`, but it hasn't worked, or I at least cannot figure out how to properly adapt it.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] (data + code) to reproduce a small graph like your example and explain how to form the groups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a list of positions/colors and a loop with [`axhspan`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.axhspan.html):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

a = np.arange(100)
df = pd.DataFrame({'var': a//25, 'value': a})

ax = sns.boxplot(data=df, x='var', y='value')

colors = ['#AC5079', '#EC5662', '#FDF7AD', '#71C18C', '#8ECEEA']
bins = [20, 40, 50, 60, 100]

base = 0
for top, c in zip(bins, colors):
    ax.axhspan(base, top, color=c, zorder=0)
    base = top
```

Output:

[image]

Variant with [`fill_between`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between.html):

```
xmin, xmax = ax.get_xlim()

base = 0
for top, c in zip(bins, colors):
    ax.fill_between([xmin, xmax], base, top, color=c, zorder=0)
    base = top
```

##### white boxes and transparency

If you want white boxes use:

```
ax = sns.boxplot(data=df, x='var', y='value', color='white')
```

For transparent colors, also set the line width to 0 (`lw=0`):

```
ax.axhspan(base, top, color=c, zorder=0, alpha=0.5, lw=0)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Note: This can be done using `fill_between`, but then you need to specify the range of `x` values to use. `axhspan` spans the entire horizontal space of the plot.

Comment: @jared I know, this is why I chose `axhspan` ;)

Comment: I know you know, I was saying it for other people since OP said they couldn't do it using `fill_between`.

Comment: @jared I added a variant ;)

Comment: You can just pass a scalar for `y1` and `y2` rather than lists. I think that's simpler.

Comment: If you want white boxes: `ax = sns.boxplot(data=df, x='var', y='value', color='white')`.